# Flutter - Multiple bodies for one home_page

Tags: flutter

So in my flutter app, when it's open, i get the type of the user from my RestApi (without account, with account type1, account type2 account type3), and each one of them has a special home_page (same appBar but different bodies with some similarities).

How can i do that ?
Do i have to create a specific route for each one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the best practice is to create a route for each user, otherwise you will end up with 4 if blocks in the same file and things will get messy fast

Comment: so there will be a lot of routes, is that ok ?

Comment: of course that is better than having a 1 million-line file, at least from maintainability and readability perspectivrs

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic widget how should a home_page should look, then create a model what information is different between users, create another file with all the data from where you get information that is related to the previous model. 
Example:
Model:

```
class Model {
 final String id;
 final String name;
 final String surname;
 Model({this.id, this.name, this.surname});
}
```

Data:

```
const User_Data = [
   Model(
   id: 'user1',
   name: 'Name1',
   surname: 'Surname1',
   ),
   Model(
   id: 'user2',
   name: 'Name1',
   surname: 'Surname1',
   ),
   ];
```

In the data you can fetch the user by id by using User_Data.firstWhere() to get user id and after get all data for that user id.

```
final userId = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;
    final selectedUser =
        User_Data.firstWhere((user) => userId == user.id);
```

Comment: it's not what i asked about really, but thanks, i'm gonna use it in something else.